# C# Registry Permission

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, registry

i want to be able to modify all subkeys of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.

I have the following manifest code:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

I have the following assembly code:

```
[assembly: RegistryPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, ViewAndModify = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT")]
```

This works:

```
 Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("._test");
```

But this fails (unless the key is programmatically created):

```
 RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("any_key");
 key.CreateSubKey("._test");
```

The user decides which key is selected, therefore i can't write down:

```
[assembly: RegistryPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, ViewAndModify = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/desired_subkey")]
```

since the desired_subkey is dynamically chosen during program execution.

So any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Registry.OpenKey(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9f66s0a.aspx) opens the key readonly.  You need to use one of the [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.opensubkey.aspx) that will give you write access.